# WP_MEMORY_LIMIT does not increase the possibility of uploading

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

As the title suggests, I am clashing against a very trivial thing, my hosting gives me the possibility to upload a file on the WP platform, up to 150mb, per test, I wanted to increase this value I tried in the three different modes that carry but none of them work, and I always result in 150mb

**1) Create php.ini**

as soon as I access ftp to my site in the main root if I don't have php.ini I create it, going to implement inside it:

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
memory_limit = 3000M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
```

**2) Update .htaccess**

within my public_html / in the .htaccess file I'm going to implement:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

final result:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# SP BEGIN php handler
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
          AddHandler fcgid-script .php .php5 .php7 .phtml
          FcgidWrapper    /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sp-ea-php71 .php
          FcgidWrapper    /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sp-ea-php71 .php5
          FcgidWrapper    /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sp-ea-php71 .php7
          FcgidWrapper    /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/sp-ea-php71 .phtml
</IfModule>
# SP END php handler
```

but I get the error: 500 Internal Server Error

**3) Directly from the `wp-config.php` file**

where I'm going to implement:

```
define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

but I always get 150mb uploads, how can I increase?

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd method which you have mentioned just needs a little modification in order to work.

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256m' ); // (need the comma otherwise from error)
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Add the above two lines just after `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` code in your `wp-config.php` file.

This should work for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to WHM, Talk to your hosting provider to increase upload memory limit. Shared hosting memory limit you can't increase in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Add a phpinfo file and call it in browser. You will get to know exactly which PHP ini file is being loaded. You need to increase the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in that ini file.

Most probably, it will be limited by the hosting company. Contact the hosting provider to get this sorted.