# PHP Memory Limit isn't increase

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

So I have try to increase my PHP memory limit for 512MB at my .user.ini file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMqkM.png)

However, at my elementor system info it's mention the PHP memory limit is still the master value which 128MB... How do I actually increase the PHP memory limit for elementor?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEFUk.jpg)

I thank in advanced

I even try to put this at my wp.config.php
define (‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘256M’);

Also don't work. Why elementor only stick with 128MB? Isn't 128MB the minimum Memory limit of elementor, why it can't be increase?

Comment: see (wordpress.stackexchange.com): [What's the difference between WP_MEMORY_LIMIT and WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270286/whats-the-difference-between-wp-memory-limit-and-wp-max-memory-limit)

Comment: see: [WP_MEMORY_LIMIT does not increase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481903/724039)

Comment: Always consider this meta resource: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - And then think twice how this can affect feedback on your questions.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes I did with the MAX now, but it still doesn't work... at elementor it still mention PHP memory limit is 128M. should I reinstall the plugin>

Comment: @Edberaga I really don't know, I haven't faced this kind of problem yet. It could be related to your hosting.